# Cruisecontrol.net 1.5.0.5972 force builds failing

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

I've just updated to the latest build of cruisecontrol.net (1.5.0.5972). I've a few teething issues and I'm not sure if they are bugs or (more likely) if I have to make some changes to the config file.

1) I cannot run a force build. When I press the button I get a popup with the following exception message:

```
System.NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented. at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Remote.CruiseServerClientBase.ListBuildParameters(String projectName) at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.WebDashboard.ServerConnection.ServerAggregatingCruiseManagerWrapper.ListBuildParameters(IProjectSpecifier projectSpecifier, String sessionToken) at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.WebDashboard.Dashboard.ProjectParametersAction.Execute(ICruiseRequest cruiseRequest) at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.WebDashboard.MVC.Cruise.CruiseActionProxyAction.Execute(IRequest request) at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.WebDashboard.MVC.Cruise.ExceptionCatchingActionProxy.Execute(IRequest request)
```

*Edit: the fix to this was to set the dashboard config backwardCompatibility property to false.*

2) There is a new AdministerDashboard page that asks for a password. Where is this password specified?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) the fix to this was to set the dashboard config backwardsCompatible property to false.

2) Default pw is ccnetrocks and is specified in deshboard.config.

edit: dashboard config may be located at
C:\Program Files\CruiseControl.NET\webdashboard\dashboard.config

example server section:
`<server name="local" url="tcp://localhost:XXX/CruiseManager.rem" allowForceBuild="true" allowStartStopBuild="true" backwardsCompatible="fals`e" />

Comment: Same issue here, but the backcompat setting didn't fix it.